# How many possibilities are there for at least $k$ consecutive heads to show up out of $n$ tosses?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, asymptotics, closed-form

Consider $n$ coin tosses. In how many ways can we have at least $k$ consecutive heads? Call this number $f(n,k)$. Is there a general expression for it? Or at least tight upper and lower bounds?

For example take $n=5,k=2$. Then the possibilities are:

HHTTT, THHTT, TTHHT,TTTHH,

HHHTT, HHTHT, HHTTH, THHHT, THTHH, THHTH, HTHHT, TTHHH, HTTHH,

HHHHT, HHHTH, HHTHH, HTHHH, THHHH,

HHHHH.

that is 19 ways

Comment: Is the sequence $THTHH$  valid as well for the case two consecutive heads?

Comment: @callculus Oops yes, you got what I meant.. I wonder if I missed anything else

Comment: I will say the answer is 19 by my method, but I cannot tell what is missing right now.

Comment: I'd do it recursively.  Count the "bad" sequences, i.e. those without a string of the form $H^k$.  if a bad sequence has at least $k$ terms then it must end in one of $\{T,TH,\cdots, TH^{k-1}\}$.

Comment: @lulu So is it too hard to get a closed form? Or at least a couple of bounds

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by a closed form.  It's like the Fibonacci recursion (just longer).  The same methods that are used there can get you a closed form solution.  Working with the largest root of the characteristic polynomial, I'd expect you could get decent asymptotics as well.

Comment: Might want to read about the [Pisot Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisotNumber.html).  I think (but did not check) that the largest root of the characteristic polynomial in this case is always a Pisot number.  Asymptotically, then, the number of bad sequences would be a constant times powers of this root.  Needs checking, of course.

Comment: @lulu Very interesting read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We consider the binary alphabet $V=\{H,T\}$. We are looking for the number $g(n,k)$  of strings of length $n$ having runs of $H$ at most length $k-1$. The wanted  number is  $$f(n,k)=2^n-g(n,k)$$

Strings with no consecutive equal characters at all are called Smirnov or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a binary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Replacing occurrences of $H$ in a Smirnov word by one up to $k-1$ $H$ generates words having runs of $H$ with length less than $k$.
\begin{align*}\
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots+z^{k-1}=\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Since there are no restrictions to the length of runs of $T$'s we replace occurrences of $T$ in a Smirnov word by one or more $T$s.
\begin{align*}\
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> The resulting generating function is by substituting (2) and (3) in (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1- \frac{\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}}-\frac{\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}
> &=\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series we obtain the number of wanted words of length $n$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(n,k)}&=2^n-g(n,k)\\
> &\color{blue}{=[z^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-2z}-\frac{1-z^k}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}\right)}
> \end{align*}

**Example:** Let's look at OPs example. We take $k=2$. We obtain with some help of Wolfram Alpha
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-2z}-\frac{1-z^2}{1-2z+z^{3}}=z^2+3 z^3 + 8z^4+\color{blue}{19} z^5 + 43 z^6 +\cdots
\end{align*}

The blue colored coefficient of $z^5$ shows there are $\color{blue}{19}$ words of length $5$ built from characters $\{H,T\}$ and runs of $H$ with length at least $k=2$ in accordance with OP's result.

Answer (score 1):

The "dual" question is easier to answer. Namely, let us define $g(n,k)$ as the number of combinations of $n$ coin tosses where at most $k$ consecutive heads can show up. By adding a $T$ in front of the sequence, it is equivalent to count a sequence of length $n+1$ composed by $k+1$ possible sequences $T$, $TH$, $THH$, ..., $TH\cdots H$ ($k$ $H$'s). So you have the recursive relation:

$$
g(n, k) = g(n-1, k) + g(n-2, k) + \cdots + g(n-k-1, k),
$$

with the initial conditions $g(n, k) = 2^n$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $g(n+1, k) = 2^{n+1}-1$. This gives you enough information for a general formula, though it will still be hard for a "pen and paper" calculation.

Comment: I need to leave now. lulu's idea is the same of mine, but I cannot elaborate, will edit this post later if needed.

Comment: +1 So is it too hard to get a closed form? Or at least a couple of bounds

Answer (score 0):

This problem is better approached by looking first at the number $g(n,k)$ of $n$ coin toss outcomes that have less than $k$ consecutive heads. Call such outcome 'valid'. Each valid outcome will start with one of T, HT, HHT,... up to H...HT with $k-1$ H's at the beginning, and the number of valid outcomes in each case will be $g(n-1,k), g(n-2,k), \dots , g(n-k,k)$. This leads to the recurrence relation: $g(n,k) = g(n-1,k) + g(n-2,k) + \cdots + g(n-k,k)$. The initial values for that recurrence are $g(1,k) = 2, g(2,k) = 4,\dots, g(k-1,k) = 2^{k-1}, g(k,k) = 2^k - 1$. Solve the recurrence, and then the function you are looking for is $f(n,k) = 2^n - g(n,k)$. The particular case you mention with $n=5$, $k=2$ yields the recurrence $g(n,2) = g(n-1,2) + g(n-2,2)$, $g(1,2) = 2$, $g(2,2) =3$, so $g(n,k)$ is the $(n+2)$th Fibonacci number, hence $g(5,2) = F_7 = 13$, and $f(5,2) - 2^5 - 13 = 19$ (besides the 17 outcomes you wrote there are two more, namely HTTHH and THTHH).